# iMac Photos stuck on Updating

Tags: icloud, imac, photos

Internal HD is toast. So just now newly running this late 2015 iMac from the external SSD it boots from, with OS Monterey.
Most iCloud syncing seems fine, Notes, etc.
But Photos is stuck showing **Updating**.

Tried turning off, then on, its iCloud connection…
(Safe boot cuts off iCloud connection…)
Accessing Photos from iCloud.com shows 12K photos and 900 videos taking 80 GB.
Searching forums it looks like I just need to WAIT, ***many*** hours, I’m told.

But… my ‘Photos Library.photoslibrary’ file never gets larger than 2.9mb so I don’t have faith that they are being downloaded.

Comment: How long are you waiting already?

Comment: It hasn't started downloading photos which is why the library isn't getting larger. Until you see the thumbnail squares appear, it's still downloading metadata

Comment: days. no change. With Activity Monitor, Photos barely shows up and there is no (elsewhere referred to): "Photos Agent" file.

Comment: It's been on with no change for two days. Could it be because I'm booting from an external SSD and it just won't do that for some reason? Yet other syncing is fine... Notes, etc.